# Spark and Scala code

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Can anybody help me?
I am new with Spark and Scala.
I'm getting some issues with this piece of code:

```
def formatRow (x) = Distance(
    x.getAs[String]("id"),
    distanceTo(
        x.getAs[Double]("pickup_latitude"), 
        x.getAs[Double]("pickup_longitude"),
        x.getAs[Double]("dropoff_latitude"),
        x.getAs[Double]("dropoff_longitude")
    )
)
```

I get the message:

> ':' expected but '(' found

But I don't know where. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate the type of x in `formatRow`:

```
def formatRow(x: Row) = Distance(x.getAs[String]("id"),  distanceTo(x.getAs[Double]("pickup_latitude"),x.getAs[Double]("pickup_longitude"),x.getAs[Double]("dropoff_latitude"),x.getAs[Double]("dropoff_longitude")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but i got an error again, but this time is about the getAs and string.

Comment: That's another different issue. You should check the API for Rows

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html

Comment: @IngridJesus when talking about errors, please always include the exact error text.  Without it it makes it much harder to help.  The definition of `Distance` would be useful here as well.

Comment: @puhlen case class Distance(id: String, distance: Double) *it's on the other line*
def formatRow x = Distance(x.getAs[String]("id"), distanceTo(x.getAs[Double]("pickup_latitude"), x.getAs[Double]("pickup_longitude"), x.getAs[Double]("dropoff_latitude"), x.getAs[Double]("dropoff_longitude")))                                                                            The error :Value getAs is not a member of String.